# Appending Data to Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase

I can't append data to m y existing firebase database....

My database: [Structure of Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4E1O.png)

My code of appending Data to it. Like written on the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

My code:

```
 let selectedYearPicker = data[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    print(selectedYearPicker)

        
       
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                          
    databaseRef.child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)).setValue([selectedYearPicker])
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Your picture looks like it's from Firestore, but the code you're using is for the Realtime Database.

Comment: but the code from the other topic where we wrote was Firestore?

Comment: On each question, you've posted links to documentation for the Realtime Database, but your image looks like Firestore to me. I could be wrong. What does it say in the console when you look at your data?

Comment: yes in the realtime database is something...but I want to have it in firestore

Comment: So have your read the Firestore documentation about how to enter data?

Comment: yes you mean this one? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: No -- you keep linking to the Realtime Database documentation. Here is the Firestore documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Comment: ok thx, but it is not working at all. let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        
        db.collection("users").document(userID).setData([
            "gender": selectedYearPicker
        ]) { err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                print("Document successfully written!")
            }
        }

Comment: but there is no gender table in the database

Comment: Firestore doesn't have "tables" per say... What does the error say when you try that code?

Comment: it is successfully created but in Firestore is nothing.

Comment: Doesn't sound right to me. Are you sure you're looking at the right user id?

Comment: yes...current user at the firebase auth?

Comment: if I print the current user, it is the right uid

Comment: Ok now it is writing into the database, but it takes a new dataset....

Comment: How I make the current user situation: let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid ?? "x"
                  Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID)

Comment: Either edit this question or close it and start a new one. It is too hard to follow code changes in comments.

Comment: added a new one....